# Metal roof decking is rotting along edges

Tags: roofing, metal-roof, fascia

I'll try to keep the backstory short: My family has an old WWII era camp that was reroofed a couple years back. At the time, money was tight so the hired help was maybe not the best.

We're currently working on renovating the camp and I've noticed that the plywood beneath the roof metal is turning black at some edges and corners. Drip edge is installed, but it appears perhaps the water is either a) running up under the edge of the metal roofing due to the low slope angle or b) causing moss on the painted fascia board which is causing water to wick up the lumber.

I'm trying to be reasonable about fixing some of these things, and am able to install some fascia myself. I'm going to kill the moss and likely install zinc strips.

What is the root cause of this problem, and how can I fix it?

I'm in West Virginia if location is very relevant.

Overhang, dripedge, and moss
[image: Overhang, drip edge, and moss]

Pic of blackened subroof from porch side

[image: Pic of blackened plywood from the porch side]

Comment: In the first photo i see you pointing to the drip flashing and a mossy, mildewed fascia board. In the second photo i am not sure what i am seeing. Perhaps the underside of the OSB decking ?  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/160362/what-is-this-small-strip-of-wood-in-front-of-fascia/160404#160404

Comment: Yes, that is the OSB from the underside.

Comment: To me it looks like it is or was leaking, were rubber sealed screws used and are the rubber seals still in place not split. Many that do not do metal professionally over tighten the screws to the point of splitting the seal if the seal is split it will leak and needs to be replaced.