# Gutter installation on fascia with or without 1x2 wood drip edge

Tags: roof, gutters, fascia

I have a similar situation to this post ([What is this small strip of wood in front of fascia?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/160362/what-is-this-small-strip-of-wood-in-front-of-fascia)) with a 1x2" presumably serving as a drip edge along the fascia. In some areas along the eaves this 1x2 was omitted. I have some drainage issues around the house and would like to install gutters. Any recommendation on the best way to do this would be very helpful. In the linked post, it appears some advice was to remove the 1x2. Is this bad practice? It is in pretty bad shape and I may need to replace it along with the fascia board (and prime/paint).

More information: The house is in the mountains and receives winter weather with moderate-to-heavy snow. I am planning to install heat rope along with the gutters.

[image]

Comment: The roof is missing a metal drip that goes over the 1x2 and directs water away.